# How to run all the commands before last occurrence of specific command in linux

Tags: linux, shell, grep, csh

For example I have a `csh` script with content

```
mkdir tmp
grep string1 file2
rm *
grep string2 ~/file2
setenv a 8
rm *
```

and I only want to execute those commands before the last occurrence of grep, which means setenv and the last rm would not be run, but all the commands before that would be run. Does anyone know the method to handle this script using another shell script? c shell is preferred. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me, please rewrite it.

Comment: `cat <script> | head -n -2` will print all but the last 2 lines

Comment: `grep -A1 grep <filename>` would also do it, in this case.

Answer (score -1):

I figure out a way to do that finally.
Since my machine only supports c shell, my script is in c shell.

```
#!/bin/csh

set line_num = "`grep -n 'grep' filename | tail -1 | grep -o '^[0-9]\+'`"
@i = 0
foreach command ("`cat filename`")
    @i += 1
    $command
    if($i == $line_num) then
        break
    endif
end
```

The first line finds out the line number of the last occurrence of "grep"
Then the foreach loop simply uses a counter to see whether we reach the command.